# Как получить все ссылки на сайте?

Tags: c#, webbrowser

ХешКод, приветствую тебя! Ребята, пожалуйста, помогите вспомнить как с сайта, который в данный момент отображается в контроле `webBrowser`, получить все ссылки? Я уже забыл, как это делать... Но я пытался вспомнить и делал так:

```
foreach(var link in webBrowser1.Document.Links)
{
listBox1.Items.Add(link);
}
```

Но беда в том, то код не работает. Как правильно получить ссылки с сайта?

Answer (score 2):

```
public ArrayList GetAllLinks(string SourceHTML)
        {
            ArrayList Links = new ArrayList();
            Match m;
            string HRefPattern = @"(?i)<\s*?a\s+[\S\s\x22\x27\x3d]*?href=[\x22\x27]?([^\s\x22\x27<>]+)[\x22\x27]?.*?>";
            m = Regex.Match(SourceHTML, HRefPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
            while (m.Success)
            {
                Links.Add(m.Groups[1].Value);
                m = m.NextMatch();
            }
            return Links;
        }
```

Ну для `listBox` используй коллекцию, наверно. Или может так засунешь, я не помню, как там с `listBox` уже :)

Тьху, только увидел что это у тебя в браузере! Тогда так делай:

```
foreach (HtmlElement elem in webBrowser1.Document.Links)
{
  var link = (elem.DomElement as HTMLAnchorElement).href;
}
```

Comment: Ого... многовато как-то, для такого.

Comment: обновил, не вчитался а вопрос

Comment: Хм.. почему-то HTMLAnchorElement подчеркивает красным...

Comment: у тебя нету экземпляра класса, попробуй вот так
HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;

    HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
    foreach (HtmlElement element in doc.Links)
    {
        HTMLAnchorElement link = (HTMLAnchorElement) element.DomElement;
        Debug.WriteLine(link.href);
    }

Comment: Строка 

HTMLAnchorElement link = (HTMLAnchorElement) element.DomElement;

слова: HTMLAnchorElement - красным
слова: Debug - красным

Comment: Нужно подключить `MSHTML Reference` к проекту, и скачать книгу не забудь по c#

Comment: А без дополнительных библиотек никак?

Comment: Бери первый вариант, который я указал в ответе.